# Is there a way to use pipenv with Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, pipenv

Is there a way to use pipenv with Jupyter notebook?

Or more specifically, with an atom nteract/hydrogen python 3 kernel?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Just tried the following with success.

In your project folder:

```
pipenv install ipykernel
pipenv shell
```

This will bring up a terminal in your virtualenv like this:

```
(my-virtualenv-name) bash-4.4$
```

In that shell do:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

Launch jupyter notebook:

```
jupyter notebook
```

In your notebook, Kernel -> Change Kernel. Your kernel should now be an option.

[image: Change Kernel Screenshot]

Source: [IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs/)

Comment: Works great, thanks. To inline the virtualenv name lookup:

 `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=\`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV\` `

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I had to get my env name with 'which python' while in my pipenv shell

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I wrote a little bash script to automate setting up the pipenv and adding the kernel. You can find it here: https://github.com/txoof/develtools/blob/master/pipenv_jupyter.sh

Comment: is it possible to further avoid the ipykernel dependency, by using a standard kernel that somehow points to the virtualenv? I'm thinking of projects where _I_ want to use jupyter, but others may not. I'd prefer to avoid anything specific to _me_ in the pipenv deps.

Comment: Note the ipykernel can be installed with one-line commands as well:

`pipenv run python -m ipykernel install --user --name=\`pipenv run basename '$VIRTUAL_ENV'\`` (standard config, venvs in ~/.venv/)

`pipenv run python -m ipykernel install --user --name=\`pipenv run dirname '$VIRTUAL_ENV' | xargs basename\`` (when `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`)

Comment: @Jim careful, then all your notebooks are using your global environment and all your pipenv-ing is in vain

Comment: @Jim now I'm second-guessing what I said...you should try setting up multiple virtual environments with pipenv, install different stuff in them that isn't in your global env, setup your kernels, then make notebooks with each kernel and see which packages you can/can't import.

Comment: @ClaytonJY I found out that I'm wrong, using pip install ipykernel in pipenv shell is same as pipenv install ipykernel. The only difference is pipenv install will record package to Pipfile and pip install doesn't.

Answer (score 50):

Install and start jupyter inside pipenv:

```
pipenv install jupyter
pipenv run jupyter notebook
```

Any other packages that are installed via pipenv (e.g. `pipenv install numpy`) will also be available to your jupyter notebook session.

Comment: This is also the most simple way for me. I just wonder, is this idiomatic? Quite contrary to how this would be done in other languages.

Answer (score 5):

Luis' answer works perfectly for jupyter notebooks.

But for hydrogen/atom specifically the recipe is:

```
pipenv install ipykernel
pipenv shell
```

launch atom from within the pipenv shell

```
> atom
```

Should be good to go!

Comment: For use here...I still had to do the `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name` command.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is based on previous answers, but I found one more step was necessary (*pipenv install notebook*). So in total:

**Step 1.** On terminal, first install both jupyter and (jupyter) notebook. In my experience, the latter had to be explicitly installed:

```bash
pipenv install jupyter notebook
```

**Step 2.** Install the Pipenv kernelspec for jupyter (modified from u-phoria's comment).

```bash
pipenv run python -m ipykernel install --user --name=`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`
```

Now the following should work:

```bash
pipenv run jupyter notebook
```

Note: If in the Pipenv shell for the virtual environment, *pipenv run* can be removed from the above. If Pipenv is being [forced to ignore virtual environments](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/_modules/pipenv/environments/), the run commands should be run in the shell for the environment

For the original question of using Atom, it can then be run by this pipenv:

```bash
pipenv run atom
```