# Connect Atom Hydrogen to Kernel in Pipenv Shell

Tags: python, kernel, atom-editor, pipenv, hydrogen

Here's a quick rundown of what I'm doing:

1. Make a folder *foo* on desktop
2. Open Atom
3. Add *foo* as project folder
4. Open *foo* in terminal (via Atom platformio-ide-terminal)
5. `cd ~/Desktop/foo`
6. Setup environment with `pipenv install numpy`
7. Start environment `pipenv shell`
8. Make a file inside *foo* called *bar.py* containing `print("hi")`
9. Open *bar.py* in Atom and **[shift + enter]** to start Hydrogen automatically. Get promted with which kernel to connect to...

**The problem:** I want to connect the kernel to running in the pipenv shell. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295871/is-there-a-way-to-use-pipenv-with-jupyter-notebook) has an answer, although the steps are a bit different.

1. Install the ipykernel in your virtual environment:
   `pipenv install ipykernel`
2. Start shell with:
   `pipenv shell`
3. Set name so Atom Hydrogen can recognize:
   `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=name-that-atom-hydrogen-will-list`
4. Start Atom (from within pipenv shell) and when you run code (control-enter), Atom should list python kernels to use (including name-that-atom-hydrogen-will-list)